# Error for save and import graph in jointjs

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I have tried to save graph in `JointJS` using `JSON.stringify` and import `JSON.parse`. But in this one I am facing error something like

> workflow - Without Images.html:1553 Uncaught TypeError: Converting
>   circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify ()

This error occurs whenever link is created and connect the element through 
`Import` of other element and use `JSON.stringfy` to save.

Any idea about it?

Comment: You can share your code as well as the error. That would help.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the graph to JSON using the toJSON method before stringifying it.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());
```

The graph could be constructed back again using fromJSON method

```
graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

The json object could be also stored and constructed to graph without stringifying it

```
var jsonObject = graph.toJSON();
graph.fromJSON(jsonObject)
```

Here's the [link](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#dia.Graph) to jointjs documentation.